# C case number+1: need brackets?

Tags: c, switch-statement

Programming in C I found out it was convenient in a switch-case to make little groups of cases by giving them the same name and add a number to it like:

```
case initiating:
break;

case (initiating+1):
break;
```

etc etc.

Currently I am still using brackets around around (initializing+1). But I wonder, do I have to do that?

would

```
case (initiating+2):
```

work?

I could not really find an anwser.

Comment: The case labels must be compile-time constants. You can't have a variable in a case-label. Unless you show us what `initiating` is, preferably in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that's all that can be said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a.aspx) a switch requires a constant expression. Every label should be known **at compile time**. Brackets are not required but can improve readability. Be sure that you really need (initiating + 2). 2 is a magic number and does not provide any additional information to the reader of your program. Using an enum will give you the same result but better readability.

The best way to verify if this works is by simply writing an example down and compiling it.

Answer (score 0):

If `initiating` is a constant it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Case labels are not required to be enclosed in parentheses, even if they are expressions containing arithmetic operations.